# How can Euclidean balls and Ellipsoids be convex sets?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A convex set is one which contains the line segment between any two points in the set. How can one prove Euclidean balls and ellipsoids are convex sets?

Comment: It is easy to show that balls are convex by considering the defining property of a ball centred at a of radius r; i.e. $B(a,r):=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\lVert x-a\rVert<r\}$ (and $\leq r$ for closed balls, etc.). Ellipsoids are similar.

Comment: Use the definition and the triangle inequality for the ball. The ellipsoid is convex as being the image of the convex set (ball) under a linear map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$ is a convex function, as a sum of two convex functions. So, if $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)=r^2$, for any $\lambda\in(0,1)$ we have:
$$ f\left((1-\lambda)x_1+\lambda x_2,(1-\lambda)y_1+\lambda y_2\right)<r^2 $$
by Jensen's inequality. But the last line is equivalent to the open segment joining $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ to lie inside the ellipsoid.